# How to compare LDA and TF-IDF?

Tags: python, text-mining, k-means, model-evaluations, lda

I am doing text mining to extract topics from documents. I started with Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA), which worked great, but then I came across TF-IDF with K-Means clustering, which worked better for me. I'd like to evaluate both but I can'f find any useful validation or metric to compare these two. How is it possible to compare these two with a useful metric?

Comment: [What are good ways of evaluating the topics generated by running LDA on a corpus?](https://www.quora.com/What-are-good-ways-of-evaluating-the-topics-generated-by-running-LDA-on-a-corpus)

Answer (score 2):

If you have the ground truth value of the documents (their topics) all you gotta do is pick a metric and compare results. For classification problems, as yours, a common metric would be f1_score; reference: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html

Comment: K-means returns cluster centroids as "topics" and LDA assigns words to the different topics. I have a bunch of other topics to describe these documents but how can I use them as the ground truth value? Could you please give me an example?

Comment: Do you have any good examples of a set of documents with the ground truth value?